# C++ C style casting pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Here's my attempt to represent a simple problem I have:

```c++
Renderable* test1 = *(Renderable**) pointerToObject;
StaticObject* test2 = *(StaticObject**) pointerToObject;
test1->setTransparency(0.5f); // Crash here.
test2->setTransparency(0.75f); // Works here.
```

`pointerToObject` type is `void*` but inside it actually points to pointer to object (like `Renderable**`).
`Renderable` is an abstract class and `StaticObject` is a child class that implements `Renderable`.
When compiled, program crashes on `test1->set()` method, but works with `test2->set()`.

Is it possible to get valid `test1` object from `pointerToObject` without knowing about `StaticObject`?

**EDIT**
This is how I store this pointer:

```
StaticObject** udata = (StaticObject**) lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(StaticObject*));
*udata = object;
```

`object` is pointer to `StaticObject`. I just noticed `sizeof(StaticObject*)` which is probably the cause of my problems. Documentation for methdod is here: [`lua_newuserdata`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_newuserdata). Is there still any way to achieve what I want without modifying `lua_newuserdata` method?

Comment: Maybe setTransparency() is not defined in Renderable (has no body) and pointerToObject is not valid pointer to StaticObject?

Comment: Please provide more information: is `setTransparency` implemented in `Renderable` or it's just a virtual function?

Comment: Yes. It is implemented in header file like this:
 virtual void setTransparency(float value) { transparency_ = value; }

Comment: Handwaving is no substitute for actual code that compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: This code does run and compile, but pasting all code would be overkill :/

Comment: @SMGhost - yes, that's always the case. Your job is to reduce it to something manageable that you can post. Almost always, doing that will lead you to the solution without having to post anything.

Comment: @SMGhost That's the point of writing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It may seems like a laborious thing to do, but the problem often solves itself in the process.

Answer (score -1):

What is the type of the `renderable` object? In general, if you convert a pointer into a `void*` (there is no cast needed to do this) you must convert it back to its original type (which requires a cast) to use it. So if the type of `renderable` is `StaticObject`, the use of `test1` is not valid.

```
StaticObject renderable;
void *pointerToObject = &renderable;
Renderable* test1 = (Renderable*)pointerToObject;     // invalid pointer
StaticObject *test2 = (StaticObject*)pointerToObject; // okay
```

Comment: The OP has already said `Renderable is an abstract class and StaticObject is a child class that implements Renderable.`

Comment: @starrify - he did not say what the type of the `renderable` object is (although it seems to have disappeared in a recent edit). There may be other types involved, and when you're doing pointer conversions with casts, knowing the **exact** types is critical. Did you **read** what I said about pointer conversions?